# batching frames for processing to reduce memory usage

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

Currently I am working a project that requires extracting frames from a video and performing actions on each frame. For this, I am using opencv-python .However, I noticed that for large video files there is considerable memory overhead. So I implemented the following functions:

```
# for converting video to frames 
def videoToFrames(self, path):
  # first need to clear all previous batches
  if (self.__batchesInDiskCount != 0):
    for i in range(1, self.__batchesInDiskCount+1):
      os.remove(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'app',
                'opencv', f'batch_{batchIndex}.npy'))

  self.__batchesInDiskCount = 0
  cap = cv2.VideoCapture(path)
  frames = []
  batchIndex = 1
  batchedFrame = 0

  while True:
    batchedFrame += 1

    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
      break

    frame = cv2.resize(frame, self.__resize)
    frame = frame[:, :, [2, 1, 0]]
    frames.append(frame)
    self.__frameToTimeStamp(cap)

    if batchedFrame == self.__batchedFramesSize:
      # store in disk for batch processing
      np.save(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'app', 'opencv',
              f'batch_{batchIndex}.npy'), np.array(frames, dtype=np.uint8))
      batchIndex += 1
      batchedFrame = 0
      self.__batchesInDiskCount += 1
      frames = []  # reset frames list

  cap.release()
  self.setFrames(np.array(frames, dtype=np.uint8)) # sets self.__frames
```

```
# for getting the frames
def yieldFrames(self):     
  batchIndex = 1
  batchesInDiskCountCopy = self.__batchesInDiskCount
  while (batchesInDiskCountCopy > 0):
    yield np.load(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'app', 'opencv', f'batch_{batchIndex}.npy'))            
    batchIndex+=1
    batchesInDiskCountCopy-=1
 
  # last batch is in memory for last call
  yield self.__frames
```

What I am doing is I am using frame count to make batches. For example, if I have a 15342 frame video and my batch size is set to 1000 then the script will create files app/opencv/batch_<1-15>.npy and keep the last 342 frames in memory. But I am not satisfied with my implementation and i would like to ask if there is a better way of capturing frames from a video and load certain frames in memory only when needed.

Comment: _what is_ the processing you need to do? what access patterns do you need? just reading straight through the video once? I see no substantial difference between reading the video as you need it, and reading it, putting the data into `npy` files, and reading those instead. that's just extra work for no benefit.

Comment: I need the frames to send to a backend which edits the frame highlighting certain defects. When I receive a frame with a defect, I want to make multiple copies of that frame  and make a new video from the old one where the frames are 'frozen'  with defects shown to the user

Comment: ooook so send individual frames (or small batches, as required by inference) to inference, and then get the verdicts back, and if you get a "hold", you just "smear" that frame over the output, and if you don't, you just emit the frames themselves? this is multiple problems. treat them as such. building the output video is a separate concern. you can easily model this as a couple of threads, where the video building thread gets frame+hold? tuples from a queue, and has to care about nothing else but dumping the right frame.

Comment: I believe this question isn't a good fit for SO. it arises from "business logic", not from any issue someone else might feasibly be able to google (find this question) or even _have_ themselves. please give the "[code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)" and "[software engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)" stack exchanges a look (review their help articles to learn what's on topic there)

Comment: sorry. I also overlooked the fact that we have a 'skiprate' where we can skip the frames. But to generate the processed video I will still need all the frames